# Selenium with PhantomJS URLError( Works in Windows fails in Ubuntu16.04)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

My scraping code works perfectly in my local computer(Windows 8) but fails in Digital Ocean droplet(Ubuntu 16.04)..Always fails on the second loop giving Bad Status Line or URLError..Have already spent a few hours googling this problem ...

Setup:

PhantomJS 2.1.1

Selenium  2.53.6

Python 2.7

```
class Elitebet:
    t1 = time.time()
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    def controller(self):
        self.driver.get("http://www.elitebetkenya.com/coupon.php?d")
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "page")))    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
        page_number = self.number_of_pages(soup)
        self.eliteparser(soup)
        for i in range(0, page_number - 10):
            page_click = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Next']")
            page_click.click() 
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "page")))
            time.sleep(randint(1,2))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
            self.eliteparser(soup)


        t2 = time.time() - self.t1
        print t2

    def number_of_pages(self, x):
        numbers = x.find("div", {"class" : "pgLnx"}).contents[2]
        return int(re.findall(r'\d+', numbers)[0])

    def eliteparser(self,x):
        tbody = x.find("tbody")
        # league level

        for i in tbody.findAll("tr", {"class": "league"}):
            league = i.get_text()
            handicap01_1, handicap01_draw, handicap01_2, handicap10_1, \
            handicap10_2, handicap10_draw, overfh15, underfh15, under25,\
            over25 = None,None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None
        # fixture level
            for each in i.find_next_siblings("tr"):
                if "league" in each.get("class", []):
                    break
                if "fixture" in each.get("class", []):
                    home = each.find("span", {"class" :"home uc"}).get_text(strip=True)
                    away = each.find("span", {"class":"away uc"}).get_text(strip=True)
                    fixture_time = each.br.get_text().strip()
                    # print "{} vs {}".format(home,away)
                    for foo in each.find_next_siblings("tr"):
                        if "fixture" in foo.get("class", []):
                            break
                        tds =  foo.findAll("td")                    
                        if tds[0].get_text().strip() == "Win-Draw-Win":
                            home_odds = tds[3].get_text()
                            draw_odds = tds[4].get_text()
                            away_odds = tds[5].get_text()
                        elif tds[0].text == "Handicap (0:1)":
                            handicap01_1 =  tds[3].get_text()
                            handicap01_draw =  tds[4].get_text()
                            handicap01_2 =  tds[5].get_text()
                        elif tds[0].text == "Double Chance":
                            oneordraw =  tds[3].get_text()
                            oneortwo =  tds[4].get_text()
                            drawortwo =  tds[5].get_text()
                        elif tds[0].text == "Asian (Draw No Bet)":
                            asian1 =  tds[3].get_text()
                            asian2 =  tds[4].get_text()
                        elif tds[0].text == "Goal Under/Over (2.5)":
                            under25 =  tds[3].get_text()
                            over25 =  tds[4].get_text()
                        elif tds[0].text == "1st Half Goal Under/Over (1.5)":
                            underfh15 =  tds[3].get_text()
                            overfh15 =  tds[4].get_text()
                        elif tds[0].text == "Goal - No Goal":
                            goal =  tds[3].get_text()
                            no_goal =  tds[4].get_text()
                        elif tds[0].text == "Odd - Even Goal":
                            odd =  tds[3].get_text()
                            even =  tds[4].get_text()
                        elif tds[0].text == "Handicap (1:0)":
                            handicap10_1 =  tds[3].get_text()
                            handicap10_draw =  tds[4].get_text()
                            handicap10_2 =  tds[5].get_text()   
                    print league
                    print "{} vs {}".format(home,away)



elite = Elitebet()

elite.controller()
```

Error message is as follows:

```
  File "elitebet.py", line 147, in <module>
    elite.controller()
  File "elitebet.py", line 45, in controller
    page_click.click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 72, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 461, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 401, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 471, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may be caused by SSL error, i suggest you to use these command-line options:

```
--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --debug=true
```

You need to use [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) callback, to find out, what's going wrong.